# Initiate elements in a dataframe with an empty lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Assuming that I do have a dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame(TYPE=c("DEL", "DEL", "DUP", "TRA", "INV", "TRA"),
CHRA=c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2"),
POSA=c(10, 15, 120, 340, 100, 220),
CHRB=c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2", "chr1"),
POSB=c(30, 100, 300, 20, 200, 320))
```

how could I initiate another 2 columns in x, where each element in these 2 columns is going to be a list (the list could be updated later). Thank you !

Shall I do,

```
for (i in 1:dim(x)[1]) { x$intersectA[i] <- list()}

for (i in 1:dim(x)[1]) { x$intersectB[i] <- list()}
```

nothing is happening.

Comment: `x$intersectA <- x$intersectB <- NA` ? But why are we doing this?

Comment: use `nrow(x)` instead of `dim(x)[1]`.

Comment: Please see these posts regarding your older questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: By "an empty lists" do you mean a list object as column in a dataframe, or just a new column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rep()` to initiate a `list()` of specific length filled with empty lists.

Use

```
x$intersectA <- rep(list(list()), nrow(x))
x$intersectB <- rep(list(list()), nrow(x))
```

to get two lists filled with empty lists.

```
> x
  TYPE CHRA POSA CHRB POSB intersectA intersectB
1  DEL chr1   10 chr1   30       NULL       NULL
2  DEL chr1   15 chr1  100       NULL       NULL
3  DUP chr1  120 chr1  300       NULL       NULL
4  TRA chr1  340 chr2   20       NULL       NULL
5  INV chr2  100 chr2  200       NULL       NULL
6  TRA chr2  220 chr1  320       NULL       NULL

> x$intersectA
[[1]]
list()

[[2]]
list()

[[3]]
list()

[[4]]
list()

[[5]]
list()

[[6]]
list()
```